# Argument of type 'Element | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'. Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

im trying to create an angualar stepper form with bs-stepper , i have install the npm and add the CDN inside the index.html,
whene i impliment the code in my componenet.ts it shows m this error:

```
Argument of type 'Element | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.

51     this.stepper = new Stepper(document.querySelector('#stepper1'), {
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**My component.ts:**

```
import Stepper from 'bs-stepper'
export class RegistreComponent implements OnInit {
  private stepper!: Stepper;
next() {
    this.stepper.next();
  }
  onSubmit() {
    return false;
  }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.stepper = new Stepper(document.querySelector('#stepper1'), {
      linear: false,
      animation: true
    })

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates, you are trying to pass in object that could be null. The type of `document.querySelector` and other DOM related querymethods is `Element|null`. Here, the Stepper class accepts argument of type Element only.

Just have a null type check and assign the value in `ngOnInit`.

```
const stepperElement = document.querySelector('#stepper1');

    if(stepperElement !== null){
    this.stepper = new Stepper(stepperElement , {
          linear: false,
          animation: true
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the value element from the querySelector in ngAfterViewInit, if not on ngOninit to a constant, and then add a null check to it.

like:

```
const el = document.querySelector('#stepper1');
if(!!el) {
  this.stepper = new Stepper{el, {    
    linear: false,
    aniimation:true
  }
 }
}
```